# C# GeckoFX Proxy Doesn't Set

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

I am trying to set proxy in GeckoFX (Version 18.0.1.0). And Visit http://www.ipchicken.com/ to check if its work or not. But it won't work for me! I tried Google as well but don't sucessed.
Here is my code.

```
  private void Browser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.type"] = 1;
        Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http"] = proxy.Split(':')[0];
        Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http_port"] = int.Parse(proxy.Split(':')[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

"it won't work" is a little ambiguous. Failing to navigate or navigating ignoring your proxy are two different failure cases.

The GeckoPreferences you are using looks correct, so the likely problem causes are one of:

1. Browser_Load isn't being called or being called after your call to navigate.

   - In this case your call to navigate will use your default internet connection settings.
   - Fix by moving you the setting of GeckoPreferences to after you XpCom.Initilize call.
2. The values you are setting are invalid or the specifyed proxy doesn't work.

   - In this case your call to navigate will fail with somthing like a connection timed out page.
   - Fix by correctly specifying a valid proxy.